# How to dynamically set background color in android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, background

Been trying to figure this out for a year now. Got a temporary workaround a long time ago, but the issue has come back up as I prepare to add new features into the app I have developed.

Main goal: Have the user be able to choose virtually any color to use as background for the app.

Current iteration: I have 2 drawable images, one green, one blue. User is able to switch between the two, but only by:

```
if (bgColor) {
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_blue_background_simple));
    }
    else {
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_green_background));
    }
}
```

bgColor is the boolean if the user has changed the background from default green, to blue.

Now that I am trying to switch over to colors, and not drawables, I have tried:

```
LayoutInflater layInflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layInflate.inflate(R.layout.main_activity_layout, null);
    mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mainActivityRelativeLayoutId);
    mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRed);
```

but it does not do anything!

So then I try to do it like it worked with the drawable images, but color (type int) is not type drawable! So this code does not work either.

The dilemma and question: I have a color picker settings/preference. The user can pick virtually any color from it and it saves it as a color of type int.
It successfully works with text color:

```
textView.setTextColor(colorPickerColor);
```

colorPickerColor is variable of type int retrieved from the color picker preference

but when trying to use that to change background of layout or views, it does nothing. Even setting a constant/hardcoded color does not change the color (as shown in code above). The only way I've been able to change the background with a color is to user either drawable (working for me now, but extremely inefficient since I would have to have a separate drawable for each selectable color, potentially millions or billions), or hexadecimal code for color, but hard coded into the XML of the layout, since putting it in code does nothing (not useful at all since user won't be able to choose).

What is the proper way to change a layout's background color by specifying a color of type int programmatically/dynamically through code? Min API my app is supporting is 14

note: I've searched, but every result that came up was either not related, or did not work.

Comment: Have you tried `view.setBackgroundColor(int color)`? Example usage: `mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);`

Comment: @Isaac has it right.  Remember the leading FF so its fully opaque.

Comment: @isaac this does not do anything. Isn't this already what I was doing?

Comment: @Aeon Psych you want to change the layout color using code? you got a long description have you tried what Isaac said

Comment: @Charuක yes I have. It does not affect anything. It seems that it's virtually the same as I have posted already

Comment: @Aeon Psych cant be can you show the way you have tried that insted of that you can even use this but its same `relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));` make sure you have a width , height to display the color

Comment: @Charuක I use mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(bgColorPicker));

bgColorPicker is an integer value received from the color picker

Comment: @Aeon Psych if you hardcode the value as my one does that appear in black?

Comment: @Charuක appears black, but not sure if it works or not. Does not change color to any other color value if specified

Comment: @Aeon Psych what do you mean Not Sure.If it appears black it Works! If it does not change to any other color means you have not passing the right value eg :   `yourLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));` this will make it orange . check the way you pass the value you can even use it as `yourLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);`

Comment: check what you get as an output from `bgColorPicker‌` post an example so i can help you

Comment: @Charuක             `mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));`
produces the same color background as `mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"‌​));`

the output of bgColorPicker changes based on the type of color selected from user input. It's some integer value. the background color does not change with bgColorPicker either, unless I do `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(bgColorPicker));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ColorDrawable would be the solution for your case. Assume that the colorPickerColor is an integer color code to draw, the background may set with the following code:

```
mainLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(colorPickerColor));
```

and if the colorPickerColor is a color resource id,

```
mainLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(colorPickerColor)));
```

Kindly note that the setBackgroundDrawable method is deprecated, you may call setBackground instead.

Comment: using the new ColorDrawable() method works, but not how you posted.

I have to use it same as how I was doing the drawable images:

getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(bgColorPicker));

Is this acceptable to use, or is bad form?

Comment: @AeonPsych, nothing good or bad, it is just depends on your cases. For example, if you just want to let user to choose a color and apply to every activity of the app, you may just setting it with the getWindow() in a base activity and all activities extends to this. If you want more flexibility, example, you may have multiple fragments navigated in an Activity, then you can set it in the mainLayout (e.g. may be the root element of the layout) of a fragment, doing this way, your app can have different colors in different screens.

Comment: weird, because I can't change the color of just the layout.
mainLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(colorPickerColor));
doesn't work for me lol.

For some reason, it only works when I change it for the getWindow()